# Failed to build quarkus application: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key can't be empty -> [Help 1]

Tags: quarkus

I try to mvn clean install the quarkus project , and it shows the error down blow .
it says the key can't be empty .and what is the key ? where can i set it ?
my maven is 3.6.3 version
and my quarkus is 1.10.1.Final

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\code\au\aws-lambda-dispatcher -Dmaven.home=D:\env\apache-maven-3.6.3 -Dclassworlds.conf=D:\env\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\m2.conf "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=65151:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file1409729559 org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2020.2.3 -s D:\env\apache-maven-3.6.3\conf\settings.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=D:\env\apache-maven-3.6.3\resp clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< com.vitalgateway.lambda:dispatcher >-----------------
[INFO] Building dispatcher 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ dispatcher ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\code\au\aws-lambda-dispatcher\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ dispatcher ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ dispatcher ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to D:\code\au\aws-lambda-dispatcher\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ dispatcher ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ dispatcher ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\code\au\aws-lambda-dispatcher\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ dispatcher ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ dispatcher ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\code\au\aws-lambda-dispatcher\target\dispatcher-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.10.1.Final:build (default) @ dispatcher ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.724 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-29T12:40:37+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.10.1.Final:build (default) on project dispatcher: Failed to build quarkus application: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key can't be empty -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Please re-run with the `-e` switch so that we can get a proper stacktrace. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I had a bad line in the `application.properties` file. This is the line:

```
 ===================
```

This line was caused by an unresolved git merge conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I accidentally used the following construct.

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "")
```

Avoid using empty names for properties.